# Zend Gdata Login with Two Step Authentication / Verification

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, zend-gdata, two-factor-authentication

I recently activated two step verification for my Gmail account and consequently noticed that my applications which use the Zend Gdata library stopped working. I disabled two factor verification and then they started working again.

I can't find anything online about using two step verification with the Zend Gdata library. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: Hi. Are you solved it ?

Comment: I have not solved this, but I also have not pursued this in several months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create application specific credentials for your applications that use Zend Gdata, and they won't need to use two step authentication.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en

Comment: the app should work for all google-account, not only for my account.